# Nested Array count and restructure

Tags: javascript, arrays

The Object returns users data with test results (pass, fail or Not-taken) based on their places. Trying to convert below object to something like this.

**1st request**

```
place_A  
   totalUsers = 2,pass = 1 (50%),fail = 1(50%), NotTaken = 0(0%)

place_B
   totalUsers = 3,pass = 1(33.3%),fail = 1(33.3%), NotTaken = 1(33.3%)

others
   totalUsers = 1,pass = 1(100%),fail = 0(0%), NotTaken = 0(0%)
```

**2nd Request** (can someone help to get this.)

```
place_A  
   totalUsers = 2,pass = 1 (50%),fail = 1(50%), NotTaken = 0(0%), name = place_A, items = objects(data of 2 users)

place_B
   totalUsers = 3,pass = 1(33.3%),fail = 1(33.3%), NotTaken = 1(33.3%), name = place_B, items = objects(data of 3 users)

others
   totalUsers = 1,pass = 1(100%),fail = 0(0%), NotTaken = 0(0%), name = others, items = objects(data of 1 user)
```

```
{
  "place_A": [
    {
      "employeeId": "1",
      "department": "A",
      "place": "place_A",
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 12
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "10",
      "department": "B",
      "place": "place_A",
      "status": "Fail",
      "score": 02
    }
  ],
  "place_B": [
    {
      "employeeId": "2",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_A",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 20
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "3",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_B",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "fail",
      "score": 05
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "4",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_B",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "",
      "score": 0
    }
  ],
  "": [
    {
      "employeeId": "6",
      "department": "someOtherDept",
      "place": null,
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 20,
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to make changes to the result of @decpk by adding items and name but only the first item is being added not all. Help please.

```
  const temp = { totalUsers: 0, pass: 0, fail: 0, notTaken: 0, items :{}, name:""}
  obj[curr].forEach(obj => {
    temp.name = obj.place;
    temp.items = obj;
  })
```

Comment: what is your expected result. should it be array of object or just an object ?

Comment: @decpk Just an object.

Comment: @decpk will it be possible to even add the percentage as above ??

Comment: It would be much easier if you can add `passPercentage`, `failPercentage` or `notTakenPercentage` as a different property. in the final object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achive this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const obj = {
  "place_A": [
    {
      "employeeId": "1",
      "department": "A",
      "place": "place_A",
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 12
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "10",
      "department": "B",
      "place": "place_A",
      "status": "Fail",
      "score": 02
    }
  ],
  "place_B": [
    {
      "employeeId": "2",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_A",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 20
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "3",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_B",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "fail",
      "score": 05
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "4",
      "department": "place_B_Dept_B",
      "place": "place_B",
      "status": "",
      "score": 0
    }
  ],
  "": [
    {
      "employeeId": "6",
      "department": "someOtherDept",
      "place": null,
      "status": "Pass",
      "score": 20,
    }
  ]
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const temp = { totalUsers: 0, pass: 0, fail: 0, notTaken: 0}
  obj[curr].forEach(obj => {
    temp.totalUsers += 1;
    temp[obj.status.toLowerCase() || "notTaken"] += 1;
  })
  acc[curr || "others"] = temp;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow amazing bro. You just rocked it. Thank you so much. God bless.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Hi bro, I have a request. Can we add the items (users) as well to our result.

Comment: @Someone123 to do that just change the first line in the `reduce` to be `const temp = { totalUsers: 0, pass: 0, fail: 0, notTaken: 0, users: obj[curr]}`